# converting a [object HTMLCollection] into string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rest, zimbra

I am trying to use data extracted from a XML file by `getElementByTagName` and it returns `HTML Collection Object` but I need this data for a sending a REST request so I need to get the HTML Collection Object to be converted into a string. How can it be done?

Here's more information:

```
com_zimbra_om.prototype._responseHandler=
        function(response){
                try{
                    sid = response.xml.getElementsByTagName("session_id");
                    this.login_user();
                    }catch(e){
                            this._showErrorMsg(e);
                            }
```

Using this function I am trying to get the `session_id` from a REST response. Here `sid` (global variable) is the HTML Collection Object. Now when I try to use this in the next function:

```
com_zimbra_om.prototype.login_user = function(){
var url = selected_server + 'services/UserService/loginUser?SID=' +
                                    sid + '&username='+
                                    selected_username +
                                    '&userpass=' + 
                                    selected_password;
                var request_url = ZmZimletBase.PROXY + AjxStringUtil.urlComponentEncode(url);
```

So here I am using `sid` which I need as a string.

So how should I convert HTML Collection Object into string??

Thanks

Comment: And how exactly should the string representation of such a collection look like? Please be more precise and provide some example code with input and output.

Comment: I doubt you get a HTMLCollection from a XML document...

Comment: @Bergi `document.getElementsByTagName("div") + ""` in firefox gives that, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14869

Comment: You can also run `var a = DOMParser();
var xml = "<node></node>";
xml = a.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml" );
xml.getElementsByTagName("node") + "";
//"[object HTMLCollection]"` To see it's not any different with XML document.

Comment: @Esailija: OK, thanks for the bug link. I expected NodeLists, too (as it happens to work in Opera for example :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With this information I can only go with

```
var objectHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("div"),
    string = [].map.call( objectHTMLCollection, function(node){
        return node.textContent || node.innerText || "";
    }).join("");
```

Comment: can we store a full html code in a string variable for eg var a =" `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`" or a raw html code in a string